# c# getting the specific form to change specific value

Tags: c#

How do I get specific opened form and change the value of specific property of the the form. I'm trying to cast Form to a specific form to change the values of that specific form.

I have multiple forms opened with dynamic name depending on the id

```
public UserChatFrm varUserChatFrm;

public void UserChatFrmOpener(string sendToEmpID)// function that will open multiple chat form depending n the senderid
{
        if (Application.OpenForms["UserChatFrm" + sendToEmpID] == null)
        {
            varUserChatFrm = new UserChatFrm(sendToEmpID);
            varUserChatFrm.Name = "UserChatFrm" + sendToEmpID;
            varUserChatFrm.Tag = "UserChatFrm" + sendToEmpID;
            varUserChatFrm.lblName.Text = sendToEmpID;
            //varUserChatFrm.Text = sendToEmpID;
            varUserChatFrm.MdiParent = Application.OpenForms["MainFrm"];
            varUserChatFrm.Show();
        }

        varUserChatFrm.BringToFront();
}
```

Here are the opened forms

UserChatFrm UserChatFrm11 -> textbox1

UserChatFrm UserChatFrm12 -> textbox1 // I want to change the text of this

UserChatFrm UserChatFrm13 -> textbox1

UserlistFrm UserlistFrm ->listview

Here's my code to get that specific form

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
    if (frm.Name == "UserChatFrm" + rdr["emp_sys_id"].ToString())// this is queried in the database to naming specific form sample "UserChatFrm11"
    {
         UserChatFrm varUsrchat = frm; // not working error which has missing cast?
         varUsrchat.textbox1.text = "sample"; // I want to change the value of specific 

 // or something like this
   Application.OpenForms["UserChatFrm" + "12"].chatbox1.text = "sample"; //not working
   }
 }
```

Could you point out what am I missing?

Comment: UserChatFrm varUsrchat = frm; should be UserChatFrm varUsrchat = (UserChatFrm)frm; and then the access modifiers for textbox1 needs to be set to public. Then after that the .text property needs to be .Text.

Comment: how stupid of me not knowing such simple code. I was struggling high and low and googling like maniac not knowing what to search. thx for the code

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the way you try to update the form, you can find a different solutions for this approach, my ideal way is create Interface and implement it for each form that you want update it, then cast the form to interface and Update the form:

```
public interface IFormUpdator<TModel> where TModel : class
{
    void UpdateForm(TModel model)
}
```

Then implement this interface for each class:

```
public Form UserChatFrm : IFormUpdator<string>
{

  public void UpdateForm(string model)
  {
     this.textbox1.text = model;
  }

  .....

}
```

then do the same for all other form which you want to update them

And you can update the form like this:

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<IFormUpdator<string>>()
   .ForEach(frm => frm.Update("Sample"));
```

Comment: with only self learning and little googling skills, I tried and still couldn't scratch the surface of your code. Maybe you could to share some thoughts or article on how to implement such programming.

Comment: sorry but I couldn't understand words in the code such as TModel, IFormUpdator<string>,etc  and how you implement it. Frankly I couldn't read and understand it. I couldn't see the big picture. I'm still researching how did you implement it I still have a long way to go. As I told you before everything to me is self learning without somebody actually teaching how to implement. Thx anyways for the idea. I'll try your idea when I'm at the level where I can read such codes.

Comment: That's the  [Generic Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I guess most of developers are using self learning and I believe it's the best way to learn anything